# If the image variable is specified, show image, if not no code

Tags: customization

This should be simple, and yet everything I'm trying blows the blog up.

I want to be able to specify an image variable in a custom field (that works great) but if that's not specified, don't include the image code. It's creating a image missing error in some browsers (IE).

Any ideas?

Thanks, Bob

Comment: would help if we could see your code.

Comment: I'm trying to, but can't return or it posts my comment.

Comment: What I have now is this to grab the variable and create the image tag: 

<img width="600" src="<?php $postimage="postimage"; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $postimage, true); ?>">

I've tried isdefined, isset to see if $postimage exists, but can't get this correct.

Answer (score 2):

you just have to check if it exists *before* outputting any markup.

```
<?php
$postimage = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'postimage', true);
if($postimage):
?>
    <img src="<?php echo $postimage; ?>" />
<?php
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I was dancing all around it, but this did the trick. I appreciate you taking the time to help. Bob